# Changing MAC address under Windows 8 on wireless device

Tags: windows, networking, network-programming

I want to spoof MAC Address on wireless device in Windows 8.1. I'm able to do this but with only specific MAC addresses. I can't put MAC address that I want. Is there anyway to do this through **regedit** I've tried many methods, but I still can't make my own MAC address, like I was able to do in WinXP . I have TP-LINK WN722N, and Intel ProWireless 3945ABG wireless adapters .

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of tools that do it for you - I use Technitium's TMAC which is free (http://www.technitium.com/tmac/index.html#download).

Be warned that Win8 is quirky with wireless adapters and won't always change their MAC address - seems that you need to use a MAC address that starts with *2, *6, *A or *E. YMMV, read also this blog post: http://blog.technitium.com/2011/05/tmac-issue-with-wireless-network.html

Comment: such tools uses api that are disabled by the Intel driver.